# How to make REST API calls that have filter added

Tags: java, json, api, rest

I am new to REST API and I want to make a REST API call which returns a JSON object

http://smlookup.dev/sec/products?search={"ABC.CP":"123A5"} - Runs fine in a browser and gives a JSON object

how do i get '?search={"ABC.CP":"12345"}'  this expression to work as it filter the records

Code i am using is

```
    String serverUrl="http://smlookup.dev/sec/products?search=";
    String search=URLEncoder.encode("={\"ABC.CP\":\"12345\"}");
    URL url = new URL(serverUrl+search);
        HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
        httpCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
        OutputStream out = httpCon.getOutputStream();

            //FAILS GIVING 405 STATUS CODE                       
        int responseCode = httpCon.getResponseCode();
```

All help or suggestions are helpful

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're setting the request method to POST; try GET instead.

Comment: @ChrisForrence same error for GET

Comment: I suspect i need to append the filter as a JSON ?.

Comment: 405 means method (GET) is not allowed. Do you control the Server code? If so please show it. If not, provide the API documentation or link to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if its normal but you dont send any data in your POST.
Furthermore you should urlencode your url, the inverted comma are not accepted like that.

```
URLEncoder.encode("={\"Xref.CP\":\"XAW3123A5\"}");
```